# Why are my toggle inputs UI not updating correctly?

Tags: ionic3, toggle, togglebutton

I am using Ionic to display a form - which is working properly. I am having trouble getting the UI to reflect the correct values.

I am getting the correct values back:

```
"optionOne":1,"optionTwo":0
```

This should tell my UI to have `optionOne` to be checked, and `optionTwo` to be un-checked.

Here is how I am getting the values:

**.ts**

```
 ....

 public myFormorm: FormGroup;

 constructor() {
     ...
     this.myObject = this.navParams.get('myObject');

     let foo = {
         id: this.myObject.id,
         title: this.myObject.title,
         optionOne: this.myObject.optionOne,
         optionTwo: this.myObject.optionTwo
     }

    this.myFormorm = this.formBuilder.group({
        title: [foo.title, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        optionOne: [foo.optionOne],
        optionTwo: [foo.optionTwo],
  });
 }
```

The values are all correct; I am just missing how to correctly set the toggle component. If I make a change, and do a `PUT`, the updated values come back correctly.

If I refresh the entire page, all is well.

**.html**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked>Option One</ion-label>
  <ion-toggle formControlName="optionOne"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

I have tried using different variations of `[checked]` on the toggle input, but if I am creating a new object instead of a put, I will get an error that `foo.optionOne` does not exist (which makes perfect sense).